# ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag while nltk.download()

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

After importing `nltk`, I tried executing the below code through Anaconda prompt.

```
nltk.download('popular', halt_on_error=False).
```

But getting always the below error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 787, in download
>   for msg in self.incr_download(info_or_id, download_dir, force):
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 636, in incr_download
>   info = self._info_or_id(info_or_id)
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 609, in _info_or_id
>   return self.info(info_or_id)
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 1019, in info
>   self._update_index()
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\downloader.py", line 962, in _update_index
>   ElementTree.parse(urlopen(self._url)).getroot()
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
>   tree.parse(source, parser)
> File "C:\Users\srath\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
>   self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
> ```
>
> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 48, column 2

I tried all these:

1. Upgrading `nltk`.
   pip install --upgrade nltk
   Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in 
   c:\users\srath\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.4.4)
   Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in 
   c:\users\srath\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)
2. `nltk.download('punkt') # same error`
3. `nltk.download('popular', halt_on_error=False)  # same error`

Comment: NLTK requires Python versions 2.6-2.7 or 3.2+. What is the python version you are currently using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.1

Comment: are you using anaconda or pip?

Comment: I am using pip commands in anaconda prompt. Also tried pip command in windows command prompt. But unfortunately, both are throwing the same error.